# Need to generate a animation like iicd.ac.in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I need to develop a banner similar to this [Website](http://www.iicd.ac.in/)

This has the animation moving when the cursor hovers over the banner. This is done using some js library but not flash. Just wanted to know the starting point for such animations. Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: why downvote? Have i asked something wrong? I am just asking for which i was clueless :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [jParallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/) ,   See these examples http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/animated-parallax-examples/

Comment: this is what i exactly wanted. . .